# Mock WS requests in Play 2.1

Tags: playframework-2.0

How do you ensure that you don't send out real http requests while running tests.

I'm having a hard time finding documentation for this.

Answer (score 1):

This is only available in Play 2.3.x, but a MockWS client is available: https://github.com/leanovate/play-mockws

```
val ws = MockWS {
  case (GET, "http://dns/url") => Action { Ok("http response") }
}

await(ws.url("http://dns/url").get()).body == "http response"
```

Comment: How would I do this in Play 2.3.x?

Comment: there is an example in the source: https://github.com/leanovate/play-mockws/blob/master/src%2Ftest%2Fscala%2Fmockws%2FExample.scala

Answer (score 0):

WS.url is static. So you need to use powermock to test static methods.

[See this tutorial](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockStatic)